# remove last character after concatenating string output by for loop?

Tags: php

```
$holder = '';

foreach($fields as $key){
    $holder .= $key.', ';
}

echo $holder;
```

I have the code above, it outputs "a, b, c, "
I want to remove the comma after c.
I tried substr and it is not working.
any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how it's done.

```
$holder = join(', ', $fields)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `implode()` to join all array elements together :

```
<?php
   $holder = implode(', ', $fields);
   echo $holder;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr like this

```
$holder = '';

foreach($fields as $key){
    $holder .= $key.', ';
}
$newholder=substr($holder, 0, -1); 
echo $newholder;
```

Comment: But it's much simpler to just do it the right way in the first place.